# expose Zeppelin interpreter UI with more options

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

ON AWS, I use Zeppelin interpreter UI to set some spark configs.
Only the gree ones (pictured) are there by default while the red ones were added by me at a later stage.
How can I set those argument to appear by default, so I can play only with the values and not the names of the properties?

I know about the spark defaults, but the UI is important to me as I'm testing different configs.
[image: Interpreter UI]

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by directly editing `conf/interpreter.json`. There are default Spark configurations which appear in Zeppelin UI. You can add whatever you want to that file. Then restart Zeppelin.

Comment: This works great manually. thanks.
I'm not sure though how to add those lines automatically when the EMR cluster first fires up.